# More intellignet "code hints" for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I like IDE to warn me if there is a potential issue with code I produced. That's why I love Eclipse and its "Markers" / "Problems" views.

Recently I learned that NetBeans seems to have probably larger database of "code hints" as it highlighted code like this:

```
String s = new Integer(42).toString();
```

...and recommended to change it to something like this:

```
String s = Integer.toString(42);
```

I'd like to have similar feature in Eclipse, but I could not find it anywhere in the Eclipse settings.

When searching for plugins that could help with this issue, I found these:

- [Lint4j](http://www.jutils.com/eclipse/) that seems to be quite old, supporting only java 6 or older
- [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) that is really good, but seems to aim to bugs only, not for recommendations on "code style" (I tested it, it didn't hint anything about the above listed example code)
- [PMD eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd-eclipse/) looks good, probably comparable to Findbugs (but as Firebugs even this one didn't cover the code above)
- [Linticator](http://linticator.com/) for C++ only, in addition this one is commercial

So my question is - is there any way to enable these extensive hints for Eclipse, using some well-hidden setting or by installing some FREE plugin?

Comment: What's wrong with `"42"`? Out of my mind: findbugs, pmd, checkstyle

Comment: @RC.:  What if the integer value is in actuality coming from another source?

Comment: If switching IDE is possible you should check out Intellij as it provides imho the best hints and completions from all the Java IDEs

Comment: @Makoto Then I'd use `String.valueOf(val)` and let the compile figure out whether `val` is a `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`.

Comment: @Andreas:  Trust me, there are infinitely better ways to handle this, but the point that I'm making is that it may not be something that one could just put quotes around and call it a `String`, is all.

Comment: I think you guys are missing the point of the question...  That is, except for @TomTom.  The OP is asking about better code hints, and probably just gave a random case.

Comment: @RC. using String literal is not an option, the actual code generates list of Strings dynamically - the code in the question is just a made-up example

Comment: PMD dropped out from my list, question edited to list that one as well.

Comment: @TomTom IntelliJ looks great, but I'm not so sure getting that one is option either (it's not "free" for commercial purposes and so I'm not so sure it would be approved)

Comment: CheckStyle is missing from the options, but I'm not sure if it would catch this one, it doesn't seem to be in the default options. That said, this is a pretty specific warning; I'm not sure that this is a generic issue, so it is less likely to be caught by default. You may want to create your own rule for this.